# How to make any sensor a wireless one

Tags: sensor, wireless

I am try to build a wireless sensor(right now I am using an adxl335 accelerometer with an analog output) but this project should be general for any sensor that outputs analog. The issue is that I have to first convert the analog to digital to transmit it over RF(I have a 12d,12e RF series which is a four channel Rf transmitter with reciever). But the issue is if I need to convert the analog to digital then I need a microcontroller for the CS as well as clock lines. This just adds enormously to the cost of the project as well as the number of hours I would spend assembling them together and a microcontroller for each sensor does not seem sensible at all. I am wondering what is the general route taken to make an accelerometer or any other sensor that outputs anolog wireless.

Comment: You could choose a sensor with digital output: http://www.analog.com/en/mems-sensors/mems-inertial-sensors/adxl345/products/product.html

Comment: Thats precisley what I was leaning towards but the issue is that it is not available anywhere where I live

Comment: What sample rate do you want? If it's fairly low you can turn an analogue voltage into a time delay between two binary signals. Could you link the datasheet for your RF module?

Comment: Not a very high sample rate(3-5Khz would be sufficient). The links are http://www.rentron.com/Files/ht-12e.pdf and http://www.datasheetcatalog.org/datasheets/166/170397_DS.pdf . The RF sensor module I use is something called wx-Tx-01 but I could not find its datasheet

Comment: As analog bandwidth and resolution requirement vary drastically, there is no such thing as a reasonable universal solution for "any" arbitrary sensor, only solutions for those have certain ranges of requirements.

Comment: Okay. Lets say I only want it for this particular sensor  whose bandwidth varies from 500 to 1600Hz . What would you suggest to be the right way to proceed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very common to take an analog signal, pass it through and ADC, into a microcontoller, and out a digital radio. There are many wireless microcontrollers with integrated radios and ADCs for just this task. One example is the [mc13224v](http://www.freescale.com/webapp/sps/site/prod_summary.jsp?code=MC13224V) that's on an [Econotag](http://www.redwirellc.com/store/node/1).

The other option would be to transmit the analog signal directly with [AM](http://www.circuitstoday.com/am-transmitter-circuit) or [FM](http://www.circuitstoday.com/long-range-fm-transmitter-1).

Comment: How would I transmit with AM/FM without the help of  a microcontroller. Also since I have a large number of sensors spending 55 dollars on each one seems too much to me.

Comment: You would transmit it by using the sensor output to control the analog AM or FM modulator, or alternatively even to control an audio oscillator driving that modulator - people have been doing telemetry since the dawn of the radio age, long before microcontrollers or even digital systems.  Most books of electronic projects will have crude examples.

Comment: I added links to AM and FM transmitters that look like they would be fun to build.

Comment: Also, the econotag is $55 but the only chip ON the econotag you need is $4 (the mc13224v). There are many wireless microcontrollers with integrated ADCs to choose from. Some are only $2. Considering all the things you are getting for that package, (the micro, the adc, the low-power sleep modes, and the transmitter and receiver) you can't beat these integrated controllers on pretty much any metric.

Answer (score 5):

You may want to consider using RF transmitter/receivers that have an onboard ADC, such as the XBee series (available from https://www.sparkfun.com/categories/111). If all you want is to ADC the analog signal and transmit it, this may be your easiest option.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider an IR transmitter Receiver link and come up with your own carrier modulation and receiver or multiplex them into one channel **depending on accuracy needed and bandwidth** for range but must use RF for longer range.

If it is low bandwidth, you can configure an inexpensive TV RF modulator with an analog TV like signal with H sync and analog MUX all the signals using grey as o and black white as peak to peak signal and using a synchronous analog Mux send all the channels in one line at say a 20KHz rate and use a nyquist filter on each channel to prevent aliasing noise. Then use a receiver to DEMUX the analog to S&H buffered outputs  Dynamic range will certainly not be as good as digital but 40dB is certainly possible with a good carrier / noise ratio.

With a vertical sync you might be able to watch it on TV. ;)